# Saving pdf in same folder where original word file is located?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, pdf

I am using MS Word 2007 in windows 7
When i try to save as pdf ,the window default opens at my document but i want to save it in "D" drive in my unniversity folder,where word file was originally located
I have almost dozens of files and it is difficult and time consuming to go through the lenghthy procedure of going from My documents to D drive and then to folder where original word file was located

Answer (score 1):

Word (Office) 2007 is out of support and it is not possible to fix it.

When you save a document in Word 2007 (Word or PDF), navigate to the folder where you wish to save it.

I checked Word on an old Vista machine here and Office does allow you to assign a different folder for saving than the one it picked.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with John that word 2007 has stopped supporting.

Maybe you can use VBA, but I don't have a Word2007 version, I didn't test it:

```
Sub test111111()
ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
"C:\XXX\XXX\test123.pdf", ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, _
OpenAfterExport:=True, OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:= _
wdExportAllDocument, From:=1, To:=1, Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, _
IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, CreateBookmarks:= _
wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, BitmapMissingFonts:= _
True, UseISO19005_1:=False
ChangeFileOpenDirectory "File save location"
End Sub
```

Run this macro command whenever you need to save it in PDF format.